# Why is the character "+" not sent to php file on ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, special-characters

In Firefox and Chrome, numerals and letters, and special characters (such as "-" and "("  ) are being received by my php ($_GET), with the exception being the character `+`. Here is my ajax request:

```
function ajaxFunction(param) {
var ajaxRequest;
try {
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e1) {
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e2) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e3) {
            alert("Something is wrong here. Please try again!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
};

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "AJAX_file.php?param=" + param, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

When a user clicks a button to call ajaxFunction(), user first fills out an input type="text" before clicking the button. As stated above, in Firefox and Chrome, numerals and letters, and special characters (such as "-", "(", and ")" ) are being received by my php file (AJAX_file.php; very simplied version of code follows but you get the gist) and echoed successfully:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';
//Lots of code
echo $_GET['param'];

?>
```

However, if user inputs the character `+` (n times, where n >= 1) there is no echoed output. Please note Firebug sees the appended user input (shown here as "++"):

```
GET http://www.mywebsite.com/AJAX_file.php?param=++ 200 OK 278ms
```

and my php error log shows no notices, warnings, nor errors. Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am using a web hosting service...perhaps this could be one of their filters in action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` is a reserved character in the URL.  You have to escape it as `%2B` if you want to send it.

Check out the [list of reserved characters you must escape](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).  You'll note that `(`, `)`, and `-` aren't on it, but `+` is.

Don't do the encoding/escaping yourself though.  In every language and framework there is a method for handling this.  In JavaScript, use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "AJAX_file.php?param=" + encodeURIComponent(param), true);
```

Comment: Yes...this was it. Thank you. I just finished building my first complete php-based site (well over 20000 total lines of code) and never needed to do encodeURIComponent (this question was for my new site). I always blocked out irrelevant special chars via JS, but needed the specials for this new site.

Answer (score 0):

You cant send "+" you need to encode your parameter
try change your code to:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "AJAX_file.php?param=" + encodeURIComponent(param), true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```